# problems with modifying AlertDialog style:

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

I have the following AlertDialog which I built using the AlertDialog.Builder, here is the code I use:

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.MyTheme );
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);

        builder.setAdapter(adapter, null);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.ok_btn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        int selectRemoveButtonId = R.string.remove_all;
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
            if (selected[i] == false) {
                selectRemoveButtonId = R.string.select_all;
            }
        }

        builder.setNeutralButton(selectRemoveButtonId,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        dialog.getListView().setDivider(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.Light_Black)));
        dialog.getListView().setDividerHeight(1);
        dialog.show();

        dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.messege_bg_selector));
        dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setHeight(100);

        changeAllSelection = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        changeAllSelection.setHeight(100);
        changeAllSelection.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.messege_bg_selector));

        changeAllSelection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((Button) v).getText().equals(getContext().getString(R.string.select_all))) 
                {
                    ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) 
                    {
                        selected[i] = true;
                        list.setItemChecked(i, true);                           
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ((Button) v).setText(R.string.remove_all);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) 
                    {
                        selected[i] = false;
                        list.setItemChecked(i, false);              
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ((Button) v).setText(R.string.select_all);
                }
            }
        });
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Now I want to change the selected parts:

**1.** I want to remove the white boarder.

**2.** I waht to change the gray color in the buttons section to black one.

does some one knows how this could be done?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use the custom layout for above purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For removing border from AlertDialog try this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder oAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);        
oAlertDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
```

Comment: I get a constuctor undefined error for this kind of Builder initialization.

Comment: This is not good for me because it for Dialog and not for AlertDialog, as well as the edit you just made for your answer.

Comment: I tried to use this one, doesn't make any change to the boarder.